# Is tf.GradientTape in TF 2.0 equivalent to tf.gradients?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am migrating my training loop to [Tensorflow 2.0 API](https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha%5C). In eager execution mode, [`tf.GradientTape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape) replaces [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients). The question is, **do they have the same functionality?** Specifically:

- In function [`gradient()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#gradient):

  - Is the parameter `output_gradients` equivalent to `grad_ys` in the old API?
  - What about parameters `colocate_gradients_with_ops`. `aggregation_method`, `gate_gradients` of [`tf.gradients`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients)? Are they deprecated due to lack of use? Can they be replaced by using other methods in 2.0 API? Are they needed in Eager Execution at all?
- Is function `jacobian()` equivalent to `tf.python.ops.parallel_for.gradients`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please find the response below.

1. Regarding `Output Gradients` and `grad_ys`: Yes, they can be considered same.

Detailed Explanation: Info about `Output Gradients` is  mentioned in [Github -> imperative_grad.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py#L48-L49) as shown below.

> output_gradients: if not None, a list of gradient provided for each
>   Target,
>       or None if we are to use the target's computed downstream gradient,

Info about `grad_ys` is mentioned in [TF Site](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) as shown below:

> grad_ys: is a list of tensors of the same length as ys that holds the
>   initial gradients for each y in ys. When grad_ys is None, we fill in a
>   tensor of '1's of the shape of y for each y in ys. A user can provide
>   their own initial grad_ys to compute the derivatives using a different
>   initial gradient for each y (e.g., if one wanted to weight the
>   gradient differently for each value in each y).

From the above explanations, and from the below code, mentioned in page 394 of the book, [Hands on ML using Scikit-Learn & Tensorflow](https://github.com/augaonkar/Hands-On-Machine-Learning/blob/master/Hands-On%20Machine%20Learning%20with%20Scikit-Lear%20-%20Aurelien%20Geron.pdf),
we can conclude that initial value of `Theta` can be a Random Value and we can pass that using the parameters, `output_gradients` or `grad_ys`.

```
theta = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n + 1, 1], -1.0, 1.0), name="theta")
gradients = tf.gradients(mse, [theta])[0]
training_op = tf.assign(theta, theta - learning_rate * gradients)
```

2. Regarding `colocate_gradients_with_ops`: Yes, it is not needed for Eager Execution as it is related to Control Flow Context of Graphs.

Detailed Explanation: `colocate_gradients_with_ops` points to the below code mentioned in [Github -> ops.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ee16fcac960ae660e0e4496658a366e2f745e1f0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L4398). Control flow Context is related to the concept of Context, which is related to Graphs, as explained in [TF Site -> Graphs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs#building_a_tfgraph)

```
 def _colocate_with_for_gradient(self, op, gradient_uid,
                                  ignore_existing=False):
    with self.colocate_with(op, ignore_existing):
      if gradient_uid is not None and self._control_flow_context is not None:
        self._control_flow_context.EnterGradientColocation(op, gradient_uid)
        try:
          yield
        finally:
          self._control_flow_context.ExitGradientColocation(op, gradient_uid)
      else:
        yield
```

3. Regarding `aggregation_method`: The equivalent of this parameter has been implemented in 2.0, named `_aggregate_grads` as shown in [Github link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py#L586)
4. Regarding `gate_gradients`: Not needed for Eager as this also is related to Graph Context.

Detailed Explanation: As shown in the below code from Github -> [gradients_utils.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_util.py#L687), if `gate_gradients` is `True`, then some operations are added to graph using the function, `_colocate_with_for_gradient`, which in turn depends on Control Flow Context of Graphs.

```
if gate_gradients and len([x for x in in_grads
                                         if x is not None]) > 1:
                with ops.device(None):
                  with ops._colocate_with_for_gradient(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
                      None,
                      gradient_uid,
                      ignore_existing=True):
                    in_grads = control_flow_ops.tuple(in_grads)
```

5. Regarding `jacobian`: Yes they are same.